# How can I estimate the parameter in the function?

Tags: r

I stuck in a problem that reproduces data in an article. (https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-019-40993-w)

[image]

Attached picture describes concentration-response curve (left), right graph means Emax of individual curve (E'max) and logEC50 (pEC50). The lower equation is the (6) equation on the manuscript.

From the manuscript,

"Simulated data (Fig. 1, left) were fitted with Eq. (10) and resulting E’MAX values were plotted against corresponding EC50 values (Fig. 1, right). Fitting Eq. (6) to the data yielded system EMAX = 0.98 ± 0.01 and logarithm of the equilibrium dissociation constant of the agonist-receptor complex KA = −5.99 ± 0.01 (parameter estimate ± SD). ."

To sum up, E'max and EC50 are given value. I need fitting the Eq.(6) to estimate Emax and KA value.

I tried that on GraphPad Prism software. First I made X, Y column (pEC50, E'max) and put in the data from graph. Then, I set non-linear user defined equation like (6) equation.

Y= EMAX - (EMAX * 10^X)/KA

Rules for intial value of EMAX is 1 (initial value to be fit), of KA is 0 (initial value to be fit).

Default of constraints of both EMAX and KA are "No constraint"

When run the user defined equation, I got different value (EMAX = 1.0, KA = 0.0).

How can I correctly estimate the Emax and KA value..?

Comment: Please include the relevant data and equations, as well as any relevant code. That will make answering your question much easier, instead of having to skim through the article for the information.

Comment: @mhh is correct.  You need to give us more infomration if we are to help you.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Also, the initial value of KA seems strange.  KA=0 implies that E'max is undefined.

Comment: Code and data used to generate the figure are included in Supplementary: https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1038%2Fs41598-019-40993-w/MediaObjects/41598_2019_40993_MOESM2_ESM.zip

Comment: @jared_mamrot, I'm not going to download and unzip a folder to find the relevant data - it should be included in the question by OP.

Comment: @mhh I absolutely agree - the information is there in the zip file for OP to try and work out the answer to their question themselves, and if OP needs more help working things out they can edit their question to suit.